# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Use previously defined variables in variable definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I don't know if there's a way to use previously defined variables in variable definition. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
variables:
- name: basePath
  value: \\somepath
- name: servicePath
  value: $(basePath)\servicePath
- name: backupPath
  value: $(basePath)\backups
```

The later variables don't recognize `basePath`. Is there a different syntax I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do something similar, here's what we have in our yaml:

```
  - name: cdn-base
    value: 'https://cdn-name.azureedge.net'
  - name: 'CDN_URL'
    value: '$(cdn-base)/$(site-name)-$(environment)/'
  - name: NODE_MODULES_CACHE_FOLDER
    value: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/node_modules
```

Might just need to wrap your strings in quotes. Also check your agent type because it might be you using windows path separator on a linux agent.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I'm using a self-hosted Windows agent

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually works!

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help :)